# Как создать виртуальный хост на убунту 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache2, virtual-hosts

На виртуальную машину `VM`  установила `hhvm` с `nginx`.
Как можно установить `virtualhost` на `nginx` для `php` проекта. Проект находится на `Bitbucket`.
На `apache` принцип создатния виртуального хоста знаю.  Օни одинаковы?

Comment: В своё время разворачивал по: [данной статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113101/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts
Все отлично работает. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Я в свое время смотрел здесь:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04 - Laravel with Nginx on ubuntu 14

Comment: это работает, но как я могу интергрировать мой php проект с nginx , и создать виртуал хост для проекта, который находится в bitbucket.?